# Adding on to a string in a loop

Tags: java, string, loops, methods

I made a method that returns a string. I'm trying to allow the string to be expanded through a for loop like so:

```
public static String averageFood(){
    String average = "";
    String temp = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++){
        temp = myGerbils[i].name + " (" + (myGerbils[i].getLabID())+ ") " + (percentFood(i)) + "%" + "\n";
        average = temp + average;
    }
    return average;
}
```

It calls upon another method in the string. When I run it, it goes fine up until it gets to the percentFood method; then, I get an error that looks like "[I@6158dd66". The percentFood Method looks like this:

```
public static int[] percentFood(int i){
    int temp;
    int temp2;
    int[] ans = new int[n1];
    for (int j = 0; j < n1; j++){
        temp = myGerbils[i].getFoodCon(j);
        temp2 = gerbilFood[j].getMaxAm();
        ans[j] = (temp/temp2);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Not necessary but look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Comment: percentFood returns an array, which can't be properly concatenated to the output string. You should process that array somehow to a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[I@6158dd66
```

This is not error you are printing object reference not it's value.

```
 (percentFood(i))
```

this will return array `ans` and you are concating it directly if you want to print Array you can do like this.

```
Arrays.toString(ans);
```

Or if you want to create `String` or `Total` by array element you can do it like this.

```
int arr[]=(percentFood(i));

for(int j:arr)
{
//concat or total
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`percentFood` returns an entire array, but in your code, you are calling `percentFood(i)` - this will return an entire array, and as an array is an object, that error you are seeing is actually the space in memory that the object is stored.

You would need to grab the array first, then iterate through it.